# onpage load....newtab open per session

Tags: jquery, onload

when I open " Site A", newtab should open automatically with " Site B" in it.

that too,once per session.

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/open-link-in-new-tab-or-new-popup.html

the above link,shows onlick event to open new tab.

but i like to have it on page onload event, with cookie session.

please help me.

Thanks
Saro

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "with cookie session", but this should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com/')
});
```

More info on `window.open`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Really though, you don't need the document ready code.  You could just do this in the `head` element on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://www.google.com/');
</script>
```

The browser's popup blocker (if any) might annoy you, though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i would like to open the website in newtab..not as popup window...

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers are configured by default to open what would previously be new windows, in new tabs.

To open a new tab easily, you could use the `window.open` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.open('http://google.com');
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

For an example, see http://jsfiddle.net/39KZ9/18/

However, without the user providing an input that triggers an event, such as clicking, the browser identifies this as a hostile act, and will almost certainly treat the new tab as a popup and block the request.

Comment: default popup blocker..blocks it..any possible way to open in new browser tab,without blocking?

Comment: No, not without the user explicitly requesting it, in the form of a window.open request fired as the result of a click or key press, or similar - it's this reason most popups nowadays only appear once you've clicked on the page.